# Query to check if a given range of date doesn't fits between multiple range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, date-range

I have a table with 2 columns, checkinDate and checkoutDate. What I have to do is to add a range in the table only if it doesn't overlap the others ranges. How can I know if a given range of dates fits between all those ranges with a query?

For example, from the following rows:

```
startDate   -   endDate
2019-12-10  -   2019-12-15
2019-12-16  -   2019-12-22
2019-12-29  -   2019-01-05
2020-01-20  -   2020-01-25
```

If the given range of date goes from *2019-12-23* to *2019-12-28*, it doesn't overlap the others ranges so I can add it in the table.

But if the range goes from from *2019-12-23* to *2019-12-30*, it overlap a range so I cannot add it in the table.

I know how to check the range line by line but not how to check it with the entire table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to check for date overlap in an insert query

```
insert into mytable(startDate, endDate)
select i.startDate, i.endDate
from (select '2019-12-23' startDate, '2019-12-30' endDate) i
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t 
    where t.startDate <= i.endDate and t.endDate >= i.startDate
)
```

The date range to insert is declared in the subquery aliased `i`. If any record in the table overlaps with that range, the insert is skipped, else it happens.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c863524c55f64e9a3a6ae536532fee2)**:

```
-- set up
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id int auto_increment primary key
   ,startDate DATE  NOT NULL 
  ,endDate   DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(startDate,endDate) VALUES ('2019-12-10','2019-12-15');
INSERT INTO mytable(startDate,endDate) VALUES ('2019-12-16','2019-12-22');
INSERT INTO mytable(startDate,endDate) VALUES ('2019-12-29','2019-01-05');
INSERT INTO mytable(startDate,endDate) VALUES ('2020-01-20','2020-01-25');

-- initial table content
select * from mytable order by startDate
```

```
id | startDate  | endDate   
-: | :--------- | :---------
 1 | 2019-12-10 | 2019-12-15
 2 | 2019-12-16 | 2019-12-22
 3 | 2019-12-29 | 2019-01-05
 4 | 2020-01-20 | 2020-01-25
```

```
-- this range does not overlap
insert into mytable(startDate, endDate)
select i.startDate, i.endDate
from (select '2019-12-23' startDate, '2019-12-30' endDate) i
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t 
    where t.startDate <= i.endDate and t.endDate >= i.startDate
)

-- confirm it was inserted
select * from mytable order by id
```

```
id | startDate  | endDate   
-: | :--------- | :---------
 1 | 2019-12-10 | 2019-12-15
 2 | 2019-12-16 | 2019-12-22
 3 | 2019-12-29 | 2019-01-05
 4 | 2020-01-20 | 2020-01-25
 5 | 2019-12-23 | 2019-12-30
```

```
-- this range overlaps
insert into mytable(startDate, endDate)
select i.startDate, i.endDate
from (select '2019-12-23' startDate, '2019-12-28' endDate) i
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t 
    where t.startDate <= i.endDate and t.endDate >= i.startDate
)

-- it was not inserted
select * from mytable order by id
```

```
id | startDate  | endDate   
-: | :--------- | :---------
 1 | 2019-12-10 | 2019-12-15
 2 | 2019-12-16 | 2019-12-22
 3 | 2019-12-29 | 2019-01-05
 4 | 2020-01-20 | 2020-01-25
 5 | 2019-12-23 | 2019-12-30
```

Comment: Another question: do you know how to improve the query to ensure that all the ranges of the table are checked except for a specific one? because to be more specific, it is not an insert query but an update, so what I have to do is take a range from the table, the user through a form changes it and therefore I have to check that the specific range does not overlap with all other ranges of the table except the taken one.

Comment: For example, taking the same table as my previous question, if the user wanted to change the range from _2020-01-20_ - _2020-01-25_ to _2020-01-20_ - _2020-01-30_, the query should allow it because the initial range will no longer exist. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well if they overlap either on of the boundaries of the given range is in an range in the table. So you could use something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE '2019-12-23' > startdate
             AND '2019-12-23' < enddate
              OR '2019-12-28' > startdate
                 AND '2019-12-28' < enddate;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the query doesn't work as I expect (it only checks the range line by line). The query of @GMB is what I was looking for.